# usequery does not map the data

Tags: reactjs, react-query

i have the request to my ba

```
import { instance } from '../api/ApiProvider';

export default async function getCurrency() {
  return instance.get(`api/Currency`);
}
```

thann i use  useQuery

```
const { data } = useQuery(['currency'], () => getCurrency);
```

and with the map try to render my curency, but it does not appear

```
<Select
                {...register('currency', {
                  required: i18next.t(
                    'modal.addWallet.validationErrorMessage.currency'
                  )
                })}
                placeholder={i18next.t('modal.addWallet.currency.placeholder')}
              >
                {data?.currency?.map((currency, id) => {
                  return <option key={id}>{currency.currencyCode}</option>;
                })}
              </Select>
```

the request i recieve but in my html it doen appear.i dont understand what i am doing bad ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to fix the second argument of `useQuery`.  You ARE passing it a function but when that function is called, it's just returning another function, not calling it.  So using

```
const { data } = useQuery(['currency'], getCurrency);
```

should work.  The following will work as well

```
const { data } = useQuery(['currency'], () => getCurrency());
```

but that's unnecessary since it's just creating an additional function for no good reason.

Comment: i tried this varient and it doen not work  {data?.currency?.map((currency, id) => {
                  return <option key={id}>{currency.currencyCode}</option>;
                })} this variant return 404 and if i use  {data.currency.map...} it return that Cannot read properties of undefined